# Enable and Disable constraints on database using aws glue

Tags: python, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I want to use aws glue connection to disable and enable constraints in tables in database instead of using jdbc connection in python.

The reason for this to avoid passing password in jdbc connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraints on DB user to disable and enable constraints in tables in database. Same user credentials should be passed in Glue Connection